# If a value in a column has multiple values in another column, how to filter based on priority in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If I have a data frame like this:

```
    id        descrip   
0   0000      x         
1   0000      y
2   0000      z  
3   1111      x        
4   1111      z        
5   2222      z         
6   3333      x         
7   3333      y
```

And I want to basically keep rows based on a priority of the descrip column, where if there is a z, then that is preferred over a y, which is preferred over an x.

So I basically want this:

```
    id        descrip   
0   0000      z        
1   1111      z        
2   2222      z                
3   3333      y
```

Not sure how I would approach this

Comment: You could sort by `descript` in descending order, then drop duplicates in the `id` column keeping the first value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby('id')['descrip'].max().reset_index()
     id descrip
0     0       z
1  1111       z
2  2222       z
3  3333       y
```

Its always good to keep a track of what is exactly preferred over what.

Lets say the ordering was different ie: `y<z<x`  where x is the most prefered. Then we could do:

```
df['descrip'] = df.descrip.astype('category').cat.reorder_categories(['y', 'z', 'x']).\
                      cat.as_ordered()

df.groupby('id')['descrip'].max().reset_index()

     id descrip
0     0       x
1  1111       x
2  2222       z
3  3333       x
```